# Email: Degrees of Security

Tags: encryption

It has been explained to me by IT that there is no such thing as totally secure email - but rather a spectrum.

If systems are secured via https and SSL what degree of encryption/security are we talking? I read somewhere that SSL is about encryption during transmission - but is thisthe same as having end to end encryption?

<sub>(If my questions aren't clear I will try and clarify as best I can.)</sub>

Comment: No, end to end encryption is not point to point encryption. TLS is transport security, email is application level security. You may use TLS in the connection to e.g. the mail server, but email security is at a higher layer.